# MongoDB Append to Object which is a value for a Field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm using PyMongo to update documents in a collection. I have a document structure that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "123XYZ",
    "location": {
        "date1": [54, 64],
        "date2": [34, 44]
    }
}
```

My payload looks like this:

```
{"date3":[30,40], "date4":[50,60]}
```

I want to update the location field for a specified _id (in this case '123XYZ') so that it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "123XYZ",
    "location": {
        "date1": [54, 64],
        "date2": [34, 44],
        "date3": [30,40],
        "date4": [50,60]
    }
}
```

I've been scouring the documentation and stack overflow, I can't find a way to simply append to the location. When I try to change the location to an array then every attempt to append the payload just creates an additional nest.

I've tried $set, $setOnInsert, $addToSet operators and others. I know there's dot notation which lets me traverse nested objects. But unpacking the payload and looping through the keys and pasting them onto the dot notation is computationally inefficient. So was wondering if there was a better way to do this?

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Are you using `updateOne` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the dictionaries use python and use the `$set` operator.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

db =  MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_one({
    "_id": "123XYZ",
    "location": {
        "date1": [54, 64],
        "date2": [34, 44]
    }
})

new_items = {"date3":[30,40], "date4":[50,60]}

filt = {"_id": "123XYZ"}

existing_items = db.mycollection.find_one(filt)

updated_location = {**existing_items.get('location'), **new_items}

db.mycollection.update_one(filt, {'$set': {'location': updated_location}})

pprint(db.mycollection.find_one())
```

result:

```
{'_id': '123XYZ',
 'location': {'date1': [54, 64],
              'date2': [34, 44],
              'date3': [30, 40],
              'date4': [50, 60]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative answer if using arrays**

This becomes easier using `$addToSet` with the `$each` operator.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

db =  MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_one({
    "_id": "123XYZ",
    "location": [
        {"date1": [54, 64]},
        {"date2": [34, 44]}
    ]
})

new_items = {"date3":[30,40]}, {"date4":[50,60]}

filt = {"_id": "123XYZ"}

db.mycollection.update_one(filt, {'$addToSet': {'location': {'$each': new_items}}})

pprint(db.mycollection.find_one())
```

result:

```
{'_id': '123XYZ',
 'location': [{'date1': [54, 64]},
              {'date2': [34, 44]},
              {'date3': [30, 40]},
              {'date4': [50, 60]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, although Belly Buster provided methods that both work, I didn't want to further nest in an array nor read and write back in a single operation. I ended up looping through every dictionary key like this:

```
for item in payload.keys():
    field = "location."+ item #The '.' is crucial here
    payload = {"$set":{field : payload[item}}
    mycol.update_one({"_id": documentID}, payload, upsert=True)
```